Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back
In magento2, When I tried to register the new customer with the unique credentials, It always threw the issue
saying:

There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account`.

Neither in the console nor in the network tab, I found an error.
I did not even figure out the code as well.
Then, when I see the log of the apache2, I found this issue:
[Thu Aug 22 07:54:16.508995 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1529] AH00163: 
    Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Aug 22 07:54:16.509028 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1529] 
    AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Thu Aug 22 10:06:50.984313 2024] [php:notice] [pid 1540] [client 127.0.0.1:37026] PHP Fatal error:  
    Uncaught Exception: User Error: 
    Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in 
    /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4169 in
    /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: 
    Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler()\n#1 
    /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(4169): 
    trigger_error()\n#2 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->__destruct()\n#3 {main}\n  
    thrown in /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 62, 
    referer: 
    http://protecta.local/backbone/catalog/category/add/key/343b12fa4d95255e0d78d8579fe13958518d9e13b15ae24c274db8905224ad75/store/0/parent/2

[Thu Aug 22 16:23:58.763274 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1529] AH00170: 
    caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

[Thu Aug 22 16:23:58.871857 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 177699] AH00163: 
    Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Aug 22 16:23:58.871895 2024] [core:notice] [pid 177699] AH00094: 
    Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

How can I resolve this so that I can register the new customer in the magento2?
I tried:

increasing the memory_limit =1024M;

disabling some third party extension.


